# Duid Kafka ingestion via Docker Compose : "No data returned from sampler" and "Bad Gateway"

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, druid

I am new to druid and kafka.
I want a druid database to ingest a kafka topic.
Druid containers are running from a docker compose file (the one found on the doc), the kafka container is running from another docker compose file in another directory. All containers share the same network.
I have created my topic : *records*.
I have a consumer.py code and a producer.py code that are working fine.
When I want to connect my kafka topic inside the druid web interface, no data is loaded. I have this message : **"No data returned from sampler"**.

When I want to ingest batch data, the wikipedia example provided by druid, I have this error : **"Bad Gateway"**

All my containers are Up.

Can you, druid and kafka lovers, help me ?

- Druid docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
version: "2.2"

volumes:
  metadata_data: {}
  middle_var: {}
  historical_var: {}
  broker_var: {}
  coordinator_var: {}
  router_var: {}
  druid_shared: {}


services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - metadata_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd
      - POSTGRES_USER=druid
      - POSTGRES_DB=druid
    networks:
      - oob


  # Need 3.5 or later for container nodes
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.5.10
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1
    networks:
      - oob

  coordinator:
    image: apache/druid:27.0.0
    container_name: coordinator
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - coordinator_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command:
      - coordinator
    env_file:
      - environment
    networks:
      - oob

  broker:
    image: apache/druid:27.0.0
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - broker_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    command:
      - broker
    env_file:
      - environment
    networks:
      - oob

  historical:
    image: apache/druid:27.0.0
    container_name: historical
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - historical_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    command:
      - historical
    env_file:
      - environment
    networks:
      - oob

  middlemanager:
    image: apache/druid:27.0.0
    container_name: middlemanager
    volumes:
      - druid_shared:/opt/shared
      - middle_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8100-8105:8100-8105"
    command:
      - middleManager
    env_file:
      - environment
    networks:
      - oob

  router:
    image: apache/druid:27.0.0
    container_name: router
    volumes:
      - router_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - coordinator
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command:
      - router
    env_file:
      - environment
    networks:
      - oob

networks:
  oob:
    name: oob
    external: true
```

- Druid environment file:

```ini
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Java tuning
#DRUID_XMX=1g
#DRUID_XMS=1g
#DRUID_MAXNEWSIZE=250m
#DRUID_NEWSIZE=250m
#DRUID_MAXDIRECTMEMORYSIZE=6172m
DRUID_SINGLE_NODE_CONF=micro-quickstart

druid_emitter_logging_logLevel=debug

druid_extensions_loadList=["druid-histogram", "druid-datasketches", "druid-lookups-cached-global", "postgresql-metadata-storage", "druid-multi-stage-query", "druid-kafka-indexing-service"]

druid_zk_service_host=zookeeper

druid_metadata_storage_host=
druid_metadata_storage_type=postgresql
druid_metadata_storage_connector_connectURI=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/druid
druid_metadata_storage_connector_user=druid
druid_metadata_storage_connector_password=pwd

druid_coordinator_balancer_strategy=cachingCost

druid_indexer_runner_javaOptsArray=["-server", "-Xmx1g", "-Xms1g", "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3g", "-Duser.timezone=UTC", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager"]
druid_indexer_fork_property_druid_processing_buffer_sizeBytes=256MiB

druid_storage_type=local
druid_storage_storageDirectory=/opt/shared/segments
druid_indexer_logs_type=file
druid_indexer_logs_directory=/opt/shared/indexing-logs

druid_processing_numThreads=2
druid_processing_numMergeBuffers=2

DRUID_LOG4J=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Configuration status="WARN"><Appenders><Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT"><PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c - %m%n"/></Console></Appenders><Loggers><Root level="info"><AppenderRef ref="Console"/></Root><Logger name="org.apache.druid.jetty.RequestLog" additivity="false" level="DEBUG"><AppenderRef ref="Console"/></Logger></Loggers></Configuration>
```

- Kafka docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  kafka_broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0
    container_name: kafka_broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka_broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@kafka_broker:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka_broker:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka_broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /tmp/kraft-combined-logs
      CLUSTER_ID: MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk
    networks:
      - oob

networks:
  oob:
    name: oob
    external: true
```

- content of the druid form to ingest kafka topic:
  [image]

> I have also tried with the container's IP but nothing changes.

- Proof that the containers are in the same network:

```bash
$ docker network inspect oob
```

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "oob",
        "Id": "7cc5a3a7b1bd6c1bbb33f0661ab085aa3ea51da58a552c76e721e0498c8543c0",
        "Created": "2023-09-21T17:38:40.970088083+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.240.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.240.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0a3c46c7cc6bb2bc16b211fd441f27afd82622bc38588ccbe159b072eb6eba6c": {
                "Name": "kafka_broker",
                "EndpointID": "ec74479ae3f77b65ad887be4771acbe134daac690ceb1fc6c81e0fdb15dea801",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:06",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.6/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "1870207fd7a1630f6d19e633c790f662c38090f1e4408b97a47e64afbf9e4b7b": {
                "Name": "router",
                "EndpointID": "148a03d24bf46ce6d6a4744ea66f27204f45118e6d126fd84b1f9bac34395470",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:05",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.5/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7b3e5540722b6f85e309263a6310e2e8b755db15f8434244e7a996f850aeb9d8": {
                "Name": "postgres",
                "EndpointID": "66dc0d46faebf4df08471ccfbcad0f032e7d4d2639564ff8006baeadf5b0bfc0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "84ed76042597d8c7ae695fbbd361eb553c007ff6aa18bf69cd0ff9438ef0dedc": {
                "Name": "zookeeper",
                "EndpointID": "2cec899b535f0570f8bcdbbdab982ccb36160e17cb0dc792efd707b6aa15660e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "869d68f3199233008c9cb583c96c7c263a491472ce27db01634fb6d04bfb7018": {
                "Name": "middlemanager",
                "EndpointID": "195e8929061c804a7ea07130c7444255fa8e4ed40b9e2360d8948e1a47a87903",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:07",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.7/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "edd7df2b2305993fec562ca4e17535783320d7b726159e7cd79325f5e13b5079": {
                "Name": "coordinator",
                "EndpointID": "032156c9dd41f6055497b8abca16a3e8602f83620bcef4172355d9ba81a3cf8c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:f0:04",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.240.4/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Kafka address is not defined anywhere in your Druid config, but `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka_broker:29092` is the address to connect with, so port 9092 shown in your image is incorrect. Also, I suggest starting with one compose file

Comment: We've built a docker compose that includes the full stack and also included a data generator to stream data live along with jupyter notebooks that guide  you on how to set everything up from data production, streaming, ingesting and querying. Take a look here: https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid